# How to create vpn extension for chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, vpn

I have a `PPTP VPN` which I can add it on VPN's on windows with windows built type but I need an extension to setup VPN's in only chrome which means I don't want the VPN effect my system and my apps I just need this VPN to work in chrome.

I want it to work like other extensions like Zenmate or Windscribe or other VPN extensions but with my own VPN server IP and username and password in `PPTP` type.

If anyone has any information please help about how to setup a vpn client in chrome or what is the JavaScript code for connecting to vpn server in extension.

Comment: You have to start with [chrome.proxy API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy). AFAIK all VPN extensions use it.